# Left Join not working (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a table Books, where I store Book data (ISBN's, Titles, Authors, etc.).  To tell which books are editions of each other I have a field Edition_Group_ISBN, which is an arbitrary ISBN from the group.

I'm having trouble getting this query, which is supposed to give the Book data and the number of other Editions based on the ISBN, to work:

```
   SELECT *, Editions_Count 
     FROM Books 
LEFT JOIN ((SELECT Edition_Group_ISBN, COUNT(*) AS Editions_Count 
              FROM Books 
             WHERE Edition_Group_ISBN IN (SELECT Edition_Group_ISBN 
                                            FROM Books)
             GROUP BY Edition_Group_ISBN) AS b 
       ) ON (Books.Edition_Group_ISBN = b.Edition_Group_ISBN 
           AND Books.Edition_Group_ISBN != NULL) 
    WHERE ISBN = 9780140447897
```

The query gives the book data for 9780140447897, but it gives the Editions_Count AS NULL, indicating that the LEFT JOIN isn't working.

Comment: I think you need another table to track edition grouping; using one arbitratry ISBN to do it rings alarm bells for me.

Comment: @staticsan I do feel it's a bit weird to store it this way, but what is the actual downside?

Comment: the upsides are:
1- its way easier to load data into the database.  it'd be much more difficult with a unique ID
2- it saves a bit of DB space

Comment: The answers given work for one book.. I'm wondering if they can be written in such a way to work with multiple ISBNs.

Comment: The downsides stem from the fact that you're re-purposing the ISBN. Your code also has to be aware that an ISBN can also mean all the editions and for one of them, it will be the same as it's ISBN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this much simpler query:

```
SELECT b.*, COUNT(*) AS Editions_count
FROM Books b JOIN Books g USING (Edition_Group_ISBN)
WHERE b.ISBN = 9780140447897
GROUP BY b.book_id;
```

I think you were making the problem much harder than you needed to.  Your original query is full of confusing subqueries, at least one of which is totally superfluous.

---

Re your comments:

Yes, it works fine to compare ISBN to multiple values this way:

```
SELECT b.*, COUNT(*) AS Editions_count
FROM Books b JOIN Books g USING (Edition_Group_ISBN)
WHERE b.ISBN IN (9780140447897, 9781934356555)
GROUP BY b.book_id;
```

`COUNT(*)` supports only a plain wildcard `*` which means count all rows in the group.

Or you can use a specific expression like `COUNT(g.Edition_Group_ISBN)` which means count all rows in the group where that expression is non-null.

But you can't use `g.*` because it's ambiguous.  Does it count all rows in the group? (if so, just use `COUNT(*)`)  Does it count non-null rows in the group?  What would that mean anyway -- count rows where *all* columns from `g` are non-null, or where *any* columns from `g` are non-null?  For these reasons, `COUNT(g.*)` is simply not a legal construction in the SQL language.

Comment: The GROUP BY clause is only sufficient in MySQL; other DBMS would make you cite all the columns in the Books table (the 'b' alias).  Since the question is tagged MySQL, that isn't an immediate problem, but for generality, it should be noted (or you could point them to a book called 'SQL Anti-Patterns').

Comment: Bill, is there a way to make this query work with multiple ISBNs being provided?

Comment: I tried this but it gets an error because of COUNT(g.*)

SELECT b.*, COUNT(g.*) AS Editions_count
FROM Books b JOIN Books g USING (Edition_Group_ISBN)
WHERE b.ISBN IN(9780140447897)

Comment: @Jonathan: Yep, thanks, MySQL is more permissive about GROUP BY than standard SQL and most other implementations.  SQLite is also permissive in this way.

Answer (score 1):

The query seems to include a number of tautologies - statements that are always true.

I think you can simplify it to

```
 SELECT books.*, b.Editions_Count 
     FROM Books 
LEFT JOIN ((SELECT Edition_Group_ISBN, COUNT(*) AS Editions_Count 
              FROM Books 
              GROUP BY Edition_Group_ISBN) AS b 
       ) ON (Books.Edition_Group_ISBN = b.Edition_Group_ISBN) 
 WHERE ISBN = 9780140447897
```

The subselect (WHERE .. IN) and the JOIN condition ID!=NULL were redundant.

You can achieve the same thing by doing a self join on the Edition_Group_ISBN:

```
SELECT b.*, count(b2.*)
FROM Books b INNER JOIN Books b2 ON (b.Edition_Group_ISBN=b2.Edition_Group_ISBN)
GROUP BY b.ISBN
HAVING b.ISBN = ...;
```

EDIT:
The fix is to remove the JOIN condition Edition_Group_ISBN!=NULL, since this expression will always be false. (A NULL operand to != returns a NLLL result.) This makes the entire join condition NULL (false) and so the left join fails.

Comment: Actually `ID != NULL` was simply incorrect, and would need to be `ID IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Thanks for picking that up. That's probably why it is not working. The comparator operator != returns NULL if one of it's operands is NULL. I was too busy cleaning up to notice first time.

Comment: George, the query works thanks to that fix.  Now I'm going to take some time to test out some of the better queries suggested here before choosing an answer.

Comment: Hmm, I'm actually curious as to why ID != NULL prevented the query from working..

Comment: Please see my edit. a NULL operand to != preduces a NULL result.

Comment: @babonk In the relational model, no two NULLs are alike.  Comparing them returns an Unknown result.  The simple answer is that a value may be NULL due to unknown data or unspecified data.  Those two situations are not the same.  IIRC, this has been expanded to 19 possible reasons for a NULL, though I can't seem to find a reference to that.  This Wikipedia article does a good job of explaining many of the gory details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29